Was Commander Morag punished for stealing starfleet files?
In the tng episode Aquiel a Klingon Commander named Morag was suspected of killing a Stafleet officer aboard a subspace communications relay. He denied the killing but, under pressure, admitted to stealing multiple messages from the relay station's files- does anyone know if he faced consequences for this, either from Starfleet or his Klingon superiors?

It's pretty clear that he didn't suffer any penalty from the Federation. As Torak says, this is a 'diplomatic matter' and Starfleet aren't going to go to war by trying to arrest an active member of the Klingon Defence Force over something as trifling as a bit of petty spying.

TORAK: This is a... diplomatic matter, Morag.   (beat)
Do not make me search your ship.
Morag looks from Torak to the grim-faced N.D. and suddenly realizes
that he's alone here. He returns to the table.
MORAG: (grudgingly) Yes... I did take the messages...

Morag never returns in the Star Trek franchise, nor in any of the Extended Universe novels, and so we never learn his ultimate fate in-canon.
I'd imagine he received a small telling off for making a superior officer look bad.

I clicked the link expecting to see General Martok slamming Kaybok's d'k tahg onto Sisko's desk.
